# Post-apocalyptic sci-fi film with giant scorpions and man with lightning powers

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

New user here trying to remember old VHS films that I watched as a kid, rented by my dad.

For this topic, I'm looking for a sci-fi movie, probably '70s or '80s, set in what I think is a post-apocalyptic world, if I recall correctly.

The film includes giant (stop-motion) scorpions and a guy, probably/likely the villain, with a mustache and long hair who draws power from lightning or something and casts bolts from his glowing eyes at one point. I also believe he was at one point driving a semi-truck and used his powers to remove people blocking his path.

I'm not referring to *Damnation Alley*, *Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone* or *Metalstorm: The Destruction of Jared-Syn* as I haven't seen clips with above mentioned aspects in them.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your description of the movie puts me in mind of the Asian fantasy/action genre, although I don't know a film with these specifics

Comment: Alright well this was a live-action Hollywood movie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any chance you might be thinking of ***[Howard the Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_the_Duck_(film))*** (1986)...?

> *Howard the Duck* (known in Europe as *Howard: A New Breed of Hero*) is a 1986 American superhero comedy film directed by Willard Huyck and starring Lea Thompson, Jeffrey Jones, and Tim Robbins. Based on the Marvel Comics character of the same name, the film was produced by Gloria Katz and written by Huyck and Katz, with George Lucas as executive producer.

Seems like a long shot, since it isn't post-apocalyptic, and features an anthropomorphic duck as the main character, which you didn't mention. But it matches your description in all other respects.

- It's from the time period you specified ('70s/'80s).
- It features a villain with long(ish) hair, a moustache, and electrical powers.

[image: The Dark Overlord 1.]

- In one scene, he's driving a semi-truck and is held up behind other vehicles having their exhaust emissions tested by the police. He zaps one police officer with electricity and blows up the cars in front of him.

[image: The Dark Overlord 2.]

- The film also features an alien that resembles a giant scorpion.

[image: The Dark Overlord 3.]

Comment: That could be it! The scene where villain in a truck is almost exactly how I remember it, and the scorpion monster is included as well. I must've confused it with a post-apocalyptic film. I'll go ahead and say you solved it @LogicDictates! Thanks!